# How to check greater than 0 or with two decimal points?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my controller I have a if function like check below

```
(model.products.ProductTypeID > 0 && categoryIdList != "" &&
 model.products.ProductName != null && model.products.SellingPrice > 0 && model.products.BasicPrice > 0 && model.products.BuyingPrice > 0
 && model.products.ReorderQuantity > 0 && model.products.ReorderLevel > 0)
```

valid inputs

```
2
2.2
2.22
```

invalid inputs

```
0
3.333
1.
```

how can I check selling price 0 or it have two decimal points only if it have 3 it shoudn't work

Comment: Please explain better what you mean. Are you saying now someone can put 0.00001 and it’s accepted and you don’t want it? Then compare >= 0.01

Comment: question edited

Comment: Are you want to use model data annotations with something like `[RegularExpression(@"\d+(\.\d{1,2})?", ErrorMessage = "Invalid input")] public decimal SellingPrice { get; set; }`? Please explain the model structure and what you're trying.

Comment: I want check before save I asked what I want I want to check in controller if input is greater than 0 or something like 3.3, 3.33 like that

Comment: @HemalHerath You want "greater than zero" & "2 decimal places" check performed in *controller action* instead of *view input validation*, don't you? Why not just filtering the input by limit to 2 decimal places and perform "greater than zero" check in controller action instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 $(function () {
        $('.number-only').keypress(function (event) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ((event.which != 46 || $this.val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
               ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) &&
               (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8))) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }

            var text = $(this).val();
            if ((event.which == 46) && (text.indexOf('.') == -1)) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if ($this.val().substring($this.val().indexOf('.')).length > 3) {
                        $this.val($this.val().substring(0, $this.val().indexOf('.') + 3));
                    }
                }, 1);
            }

            if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) &&
                (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 4) &&
                (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8) &&
                ($(this)[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 4)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });

        $('.number-only').bind("paste", function (e) {
            var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
            if ($.isNumeric(text)) {
                if ((text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 3) && (text.indexOf('.') > -1)) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).val(text.substring(0, text.indexOf('.') + 3));
                }
            }
            else {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
        //$('.number-only').keypress(function (e) {

        //    if (isNaN(this.value + "" + String.fromCharCode(e.charCode))) return false;


        //})
        //.on("cut copy paste", function (e) {
        //    e.preventDefault();
        //});
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input name="Tsm_Rate" id="Pr" placeholder="Price" class="form-control number-only" type="text"/>
```

you can do this by using j query :_ here you can enter only four digit after decimal it's upto you how many digit you want after decimal point

Comment: The question is not tagged javascritpt, and javascript does not work in a c# controller method!

Comment: if you can do it at view side why you need to do it controller side!

Comment: You mean apart from the fact the question asks for server side code! Anyone can bypass client side code. Data must always be validated on the server.

Comment: instead  of wasting time to reply.. give if you have better solution